# async wcf service returning null

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

Hi i am creating a async WCF service and consuming it in HTML application, but every time i am getting null from service. I am new in async methods so please guide me,I am sharing my code here:

**Service.cs**

```
public static async Task<string> GetTJSON()
{
 string responseData = string.Empty;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://api.xyz.com/json/feeds?system=apios").ConfigureAwait(false))
           {
                responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseData;
            }
        }
}

public async Task<string> getJ()
    {
        var json = await GetTJSON();
        return json.ToString();
}
```

**Iservice.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetJsonNet1", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
Task<string> getJ();
```

**HTML/Jquery**

```
var GetJsonNet = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:59835/Service1.svc/GetJsonNet1",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.GetEmployeeJSONResult;
                console.log(result);
                var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                alert('s:' + obj);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('e:'+xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is `data` null? Or just `result` is null?

Comment: can you see if awaiting on `GetTJSON` produces the expected result.?

Comment: it is not returning back to getJ() function. it send response to html at await httpClient.GetAsync then processing executing rest of code so i am getting result null